# When vs If for causality

Tags: meaning, word-choice, sentence-meaning, difference

What's the difference between these two sentences

> When the user runs the program or file, the malicious payload of the Trojan is injected into the system

> If the user runs the program or file, the malicious payload of the Trojan is injected into the system

Which is a native speaker more likely to use? What is different about their meanings or implications?

Answer (score 2):

Do you think a user will run the program?  If you think "yes, they will" then  use "When".  If you think it is possible but you are not sure, the use "if".

> When Jack comes home, I will give him this present. (I know Jack will come home)

> If Jack comes home, I will give him this present. (It is possible that Jack won't come home)

In many cases, there is little difference.  You might think "Yes, someone will run the program eventually, but probably not soon" and so both "when" and "if" sound normal and natural.

Answer (score -1):

`if` is a `conjunction` It is used to express conditions or suppositions.

`when` is an `adverb` It is used to express that something happens, happened, or is happening at some point in time.

Comment: I have downvoted your answer because the second part is incorrect - or, at best, only partially correct. Check it out: http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-when/

Comment: If my answer is incorrect, you are saying that that `when` is not `adverb`.
In this case, my answer is **correct**, but it is incomplete.

Comment: As the grammar source points out, the function of **when** depends on how it is used. It can act as any of several parts of speech. In the examples above, the words **if** and **when** serve identical functions as conjunctions connecting the two clauses.

Comment: Totally agree with your point